# MySQL - This AND this OR this

Tags: php, mysql

This is for an update field and I am checking to be sure the number AND keyword -> OR the campaign name exist to prevent duplicates.

This query is not acting as expected:

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("
    SELECT * 
    FROM campaigns 
    WHERE number = :number AND keyword = :keyword
    OR name LIKE :name"
);
```

I want it to check if (number=number AND keyword=keyword) OR (name=name) - As two different statements not related to eachother. Even if I wrap them in brackets I still get not the right results.

Any help?

Comment: Can you give an example of the data in the DB, the expected result and the actual result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**LIKE** Also needs to have % if it is not supposed to work like **=** Operator

```
SELECT * FROM campaigns WHERE (number = :number AND keyword = :keyword) OR name LIKE %:name%"
```

Answer (score 1):

try it like that

```
     $STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * 
                   FROM campaigns 
                   WHERE (number = :number AND keyword = :keyword)
                   OR name LIKE :name"
                   );
```